# Cannot use PSQL with Qt

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database in Qt:

```cpp
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
db.setUserName("postgres");
db.setPassword("pass");
db.setPort(5432);
db.open()
```

However, I get this error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC
```

I am running macOS Big Sur on M1 MacBook Pro. `postgres` is installed via Homebrew. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the postgresql Qt plugin. Either install from where you installed Qt from or compile the plugin by yourself: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers